# Passing in An Operator as a Parameter

Tags: scala, function, parameters, pattern-matching, operators

I'm doing an exercise in "Scala for the Impatient", Chapter 14, Q8:

Essentially I need to create a function (**utilizing pattern matching**) that takes in an operator and nodes, and it outputs the result of the operation. E.G. Node(+, Node(*, Leaf(2), Leaf(3)) Leaf(1)) should output 7.

Here are some of the given classes:

```
sealed abstract class BinaryTree
case class Leaf(value: Int) extends BinaryTree
```

So I create a Node class, but I'm having difficulties figuring out how to pass in the operator.

```
case class Node(op: Function (what goes here?) , leaves: BinaryTree*) extends BinaryTree
```

I want to use pattern matching like so:

```
  tree match {
    case Node(op, leaves @ _*) => op match {
      case op : Function => leaves.reduceLeft(_ op _)
    }
    case leaf: Leaf => leaf.value
```

But the

```
case op : Function => leaves.reduceLeft(_ op _)
```

part is wrong. I don't know how to use the operator that's being passed in the Node class. What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I am assuming the operator will be always going to be binary hence, our So called BinaryTree will have atleast two operands :

```
  trait BinaryTree

  case class Leaf(value: Int) extends BinaryTree

  case class Node(op: Function2[Int, Int, Int], l1: BinaryTree*) extends BinaryTree

  object Operators {
    val + = (a: Int, b: Int) => a + b
    val * = (a: Int, b: Int) => a * b
  }

  def f(tree: BinaryTree): Int = {
    tree match {
      case n: Node => n.l1.map(f).reduceLeft((r,c) => n.op(r,c))
      case leaf: Leaf => leaf.value
    }
  }
```

Some test results:

Simple one:

```
scala>   f(Node(Operators.*,Leaf(4),Leaf(2),Leaf(3)))
res4: Int = 24

scala> f(Node(Operators.+, 
         Node(Operators.*, Leaf(2), Leaf(1), Leaf(4), Leaf(5)), Leaf(6)))
res5: Int = 46

scala>   f(Node(Operators.+, 
          Node(Operators.*, Leaf(2), Leaf(1), Leaf(4), Leaf(5)),
          Node(Operators.+,Leaf(9),Leaf(9)), Leaf(6)))
res6: Int = 64
```

Quite complex:

```
scala> f(Node(Operators.+,
          Node(Operators.*, Leaf(2), Leaf(1), 
          Node(Operators.* ,Leaf(4), Leaf(5) ,Leaf(2))),
          Node(Operators.+,Leaf(9),Leaf(9)), Leaf(6),
          Node(Operators.*, Leaf(2), Leaf(2))))
res7: Int = 108
```

Comment: Oops, I'm sorry for the confusion. I've worded the tree wrong, it isn't a Binary Tree. It can have an arbitrary amount of leaf nodes, so:

e.g. Node(+, Leaf(2), Leaf(1), Leaf(4), Leaf(5)) is valid.

Comment: That is why I had the leaves : BinaryTree* parameter in the Node case class.

Comment: @averageUsername123 :Edited my ans as per requirement. and you can define other operators like `+` and `*`

Comment: How would you account for something like this:
e.g. f(Node(Operators.-, Leaf(2))) ? The answer would be -2.

Comment: I assumed all the arthemetic opertors as Binary and assuming that they will have two operands but just to handle this special case of negation you can modify accordingly and that shouldn't be much difficult ;)

Comment: unary operations has different behaviour.  - (minus) is just one example, but what should be the case for * or /  etc?

Answer (score 2):

It has more elegant solutions, but since you want it with pattern matching:

```js
sealed abstract class BinaryTree
case class Leaf(value: Int) extends BinaryTree
case class Node(op: (Int, Int) => Int , leaves: BinaryTree*) extends BinaryTree

def calc(tree: BinaryTree): Int = tree match {
  case Leaf(v) => v
  case Node(op, h, leaves @ _*) => leaves.foldLeft(calc(h))((a,b) => op(a,calc(b)))
}

object Operators {
  def +(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a + b
  def *(a: Int, b: Int): Int = a * b
}

val tree = Node(Operators.+, Node(Operators.*, Leaf(9), Leaf(3)), Leaf(1))

calc(tree)
```

Comment: @curious answer is pretty much the same.  I post this one before i saw his updates.